# LibGDX World/Screen coordinates to Viewport coordinates (with camera zoom)

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, viewport

I have a game map that is larger than the viewport, so the camera moves around. The player can also zoom the camera in/out. When anywhere on the screen is tapped I get the device screen coordinates. So if I have a 1920x1080 screen and tap the upper right corner i get (1920, 1080) whereas if I have a 1280x720 screen tapping at the same place gives a (1280, 720).

My viewport (virtual screen size) is set to 1280x720. If I use `cam.unproject(Vector2)` or `viewport.unproject(Vector2)` I get the corresponding world coordinates. So if the camera is not translated or zoomed. Tapping the upper left corner on any screen size gives a (1280,720). But if I scroll the map up and to the right I get bigger values than (1280,720). In fact I get `(1280 + camera.position.x, 720 + camera.position.y)`. And using zoom complicates things even more and I have to manually calculate what I'm looking for.

My question is, how can I get the viewport coordinate and not the world coordinate? Does LibGDX have a way around this?

Comment: `myViewport.screenX` & `myViewport.screenY`? But my guess would be these values would be relative to the bottom corner of your screen in pixels. What is it exactly what you want? You viewport renders what the camera sees, I think what you really want is camera coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
    public static Vector3 MultiplyPoint(Matrix4 m, Vector3 point)
{
    Vector3 result = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    result.x = m.val[Matrix4.M00] * point.x + m.val[Matrix4.M01] * point.y +  m.val[Matrix4.M02]* point.z +  m.val[Matrix4.M03];
    result.y = m.val[Matrix4.M10] * point.x + m.val[Matrix4.M11] * point.y + m.val[Matrix4.M12] * point.z + m.val[Matrix4.M13];
    result.z = m.val[Matrix4.M20] * point.x + m.val[Matrix4.M21] * point.y + m.val[Matrix4.M22] * point.z + m.val[Matrix4.M23];
    float num = m.val[Matrix4.M30] * point.x + m.val[Matrix4.M31] * point.y + m.val[Matrix4.M32] * point.z + m.val[Matrix4.M33];
    num = 1f / num;
    result.x *= num;
    result.y *= num;
    result.z *= num;
    return result;
}

public static Vector2 WorldToScreenPoint(float x, float y)
{
    Matrix4 V = Constants.Camera.view;
    Matrix4 P = Constants.Camera.projection;
    
    Matrix4 MVP = P.mul(V); // Skipping M, point in world coordinates
    Vector3 screenPos = MultiplyPoint(MVP, new Vector3(x, y, 0));
    
    Vector3 screenPoint = new Vector3(screenPos.x + 1f, screenPos.y + 1f, screenPos.z + 1f).scl(0.5f); // returns x, y in [0, 1] internal. 
    
    return new Vector2(screenPoint.x * Constants.GlobalWidth, screenPoint.y * Constants.GlobalHeight); // multiply by viewport width and height to get the actual screen coordinates.
}
```